# Are vectors meaningless without proper nomenclature?

Tags: vectors

If I am presented with a vector in the form $\vec r=x\hat i+y\hat j+z\hat k$, I always face an amiguity if it represents a
position vector or any other vector. I am unable to put it exactly into words so I have tried to depict this in the picture below.

[image]

If $\vec r=(d-a)\hat i+(e-b)\hat j+(f-c)\hat k$ is given then we can conclude two vectors from it.

So, I have come to the conclusion that a vector is meaningless without proper nomenclature.

I have tried to resolve this in the picture below.[image]

Now $\vec OC$ can be used to represent one vector and $\vec AB$ can be used to represent another vector.

Are my conclusions correct?

Edit: One of my teachers told me that both the interpretations would give the same vector i.e. same magnitude and direction. Is this true?
I think this would clear all my doubts.

Comment: I am using android  mobile to post questions can anyone suggest what app/website they find best to draw figures similar to above figures.

Comment: You can use GeoGebra or Desmos for that.

Comment: You need to learn what an **affine space** is, allowing to write expressions like $\vec{AB}=B-A$, etc. and qll will be clearer.

Comment: @JeanMarie Sir, l tried to read about affine spaces and somewhat understood that my doubt is related to that but would you mind elaborating a dumbed down version  of affine space keeping in mind my doubt?

Comment: Those pictures are not drawn correctly! Try plugging in some actual numbers. The arrow from the origin to the point $(d-a, e-b, f-c)$ should be *parallel* to the arrow from the point $(a,b,c)$ to the point $(d,e,f)$. You should draw those pictures very carefully and try using specific numbers; maybe even use graph paper. Then you'll see that your teacher was correct: both arrows have the same magnitude and direction.

Comment: @littleO Thank you sir.Yes, I now understand that those two figures are wrong but that is exactly what I got wrong and this doubt arose. If both those vectors are parallel then there is no confusion. I have got my doubt cleared.